# Do extra parameters in JSONConfigFile affect the parsing of a JSON file

Tags: java, json

I currently have a class in my project that defines a structure of a JSON file and uses this information to parse the JSON file. I was wondering what would happen if my JSON file did not have these specified parameters/extra parameters

```
public class JSONLoader {
    public class JSONListing {
      public int price;
      public int bedrooms;
      public int bathrooms;
      public int sqft_living;
      public int sqft_lot;
      public int floors;
      public String waterfront;
      public int sqft_above;
      public int sqft_basement;
      public int yr_built;
      public int latitude;
      public int longitute;
      public String Type;
}

public static JSONListing parse(String configfile) {
     Gson gson = new Gson();
     try (Reader reader = new FileReader(new File(configFile))) {      
     ....
     }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you implement the parsing part.
Even sticking to Gson, you still have several options.
Are you using [fromJson](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.5/com/google/gson/Gson.html#fromJson-com.google.gson.JsonElement-java.lang.Class-) method?
If so, it ignores unknown properties by default.
If there is something more in JSON file that is not part of your model, it should be ignored.

Comment: Yes i'm using the fromJson method. What about if I try getting a value from the JSON file where it doesn't exist. Would it just return a null value or should I catch and propogate it as a IllegalArguementException/NullPointerException.

Comment: Missing fields would be mapped to null. Having primitives like in your model, you will end up with the initial value (0).

Comment: thanks @KnotGillCup is there any way you could answer my follow up question  posted below in asnwer

Answer (score 0):

Answer: (in comments)

follow up question:

Would you also know how fromJson method handles single hierarchy JSON files. For example my file is as such:

[
  {
    "price": 221900,
    "bedrooms": 3,
    "bathrooms": 1,
    "sqft_living": 1180,
    "sqft_lot": 5650,
    "floors": 1,
    "waterfront": "FALSE",
    "sqft_above": 1180,
    "sqft_basement": 0,
    "yr_built": 1955,
    "lat": 47.5112,
    "long": -122.257,
    "sqft_living15": 1340,
    "sqft_lot15": 5650,
    "Type": "condo"
  },
  {
    "price": 538000,
    "bedrooms": 3,
    "bathrooms": 2,
    "sqft_living": 2570,
    "sqft_lot": 7242,
    "floors": 2,
    "waterfront": "FALSE",
    "sqft_above": 2170,
    "sqft_basement": 400,
    "yr_built": 1951,
    "lat": 47.721,
    "long": -122.319,
    "sqft_living15": 1690,
    "sqft_lot15": 7639,
    "Type": "studio"
  }, ...

So based on my above JSON listing object would gson.fromJson(reader, JSONListing.class) return a JSONListing[] or just a single JSONListing obejct (which doesn't really make sense)

Comment: I would declare a Type and parse to a List or Collection.

`Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<JSONListing>>(){}.getType();
List<JSONListing> jsonListings = new Gson().fromJson(jsonArray, listType);`